# Custom NSS module - Successfully compiled but not called and not generating any log

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to implement a custom NSS module based on HTTP.

But I can't achieve to make work a basic example, the code is not even called. According to https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Services-in-the-NSS-configuration.html#Services-in-the-NSS-configuration, I got a `libnss_http.so.2` file stored in `/usr/lib` and set in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` like this

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         files http
group:          files
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

But `getent passwd unknown` does not create any file log.

`nss_http-passwd.c`

```c
#include "nss_http.h"

// Called to open the passwd file
enum nss_status
_nss_http_setpwent(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen("/tmp/test.txt", "w+");
   fputs("This is testing for fputs...\n", fp);
   fclose(fp);

    return NSS_STATUS_UNAVAIL;
}

// Called to close the passwd file
enum nss_status
_nss_http_endpwent(void)
{
    return NSS_STATUS_UNAVAIL;
}


// Called to look up next entry in passwd file
enum nss_status
_nss_http_getpwent_r(struct passwd *result, char *buffer, size_t buflen, int *errnop)
{
    return NSS_STATUS_UNAVAIL;
}

enum nss_status
_nss_http_getpwbyuid_r(uid_t uid, struct passwd *result, char *buffer, size_t buflen, int *errnop)
{
    return NSS_STATUS_UNAVAIL;
}

// Find a passwd by name
enum nss_status
_nss_http_getpwbyname_r(const char *name, struct passwd *result, char *buffer, size_t buflen, int *errnop)
{
    return NSS_STATUS_UNAVAIL;
}
```

`nss_http.h`

```c
#ifndef NSS_HTTP_H
#define NSS_HTTP_H

#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <jansson.h>
#include <nss.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <shadow.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NSS_HTTP_INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE (256 * 1024)  /* 256 KB */
#define NSS_HTTP_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE (10 * 1024 * 1024)  /* 10 MB */

extern char *nss_http_request(const char *);
extern size_t j_strlen(json_t *);

#endif /* NSS_HTTP_H */
```

`Makefile`

```c
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror -fPIC -std=c99

LD_SONAME=-Wl,-soname,libnss_http.so.2
LIBRARY=libnss_http.so.2.0
LINKS=libnss_http.so.2 libnss_http.so

DESTDIR=/
PREFIX=$(DESTDIR)/usr
LIBDIR=$(PREFIX)/lib
BUILD=.libs

default: build
build: nss_http

nss_http_build_dir:
    [ -d $(BUILD) ] || mkdir $(BUILD)

nss_http-passwd:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c nss_http-passwd.c -o $(BUILD)/nss_http-passwd.o



nss_http_services: nss_http-passwd

nss_http: nss_http_build_dir nss_http_services
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c nss_http.c -o $(BUILD)/nss_http.o

    $(CC) -shared $(LD_SONAME) -o $(BUILD)/$(LIBRARY) \
        $(BUILD)/nss_http.o \
        $(BUILD)/nss_http-passwd.o \
        -lcurl -ljansson

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD)

install:
    [ -d $(LIBDIR) ] || install -d $(LIBDIR)
    install $(BUILD)/$(LIBRARY) $(LIBDIR)
    cd $(LIBDIR); for link in $(LINKS); do ln -sf $(LIBRARY) $$link ; done

.PHONY: clean install nss_http_build_dir nss_http
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to copy the shared library to `/usr/lib64` ?

Comment: @pifor It did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, but pifor's suggestion to copy the shared libraries into /usr/lib64 did fix this on a CentOS 7 machine.  Look for the location of other libnss_xxx libraries on your installation and copy the pattern you see.

A second thing to watch out for is that all of your shared library dependencies (libjanssen, libcurl) can be properly resolved when your library is loaded dynamically at runtime.  If not, the callout will silently fail.

Comment: Just use `strace` to debug and ensure about loading the module and required so's.